# Why is my close value in my strategy stopped updating every tick after 2 minutes of running?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

This is a really simple code but I must figure out the problem in order to work with my real strategy:

```
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick = true)

plot(close)
```

It simply plots the close in the chart, it worked correctly as expected, which is to plot the close price every tick, but after about 2 minutes of adding it to the chart, it started to be pretty slow and delayed in plotting the close, the close value in the strategy and in the chart starting to be mismatched although it should be updated every tick, now it updates the close in the chart every 20 sec instead of every tick. Anybody knows the problem here?

[image: close value in the strategy not matching the chart]

Comment: I suggest you to contact support about this issue.

Comment: I'll do it thanks for the suggestion :)